# Slow image(frame) grabbing from video with OpenCV's VideoCapture and Python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, video-processing

what i want is to grap random-indexed frames from a long video (~50 minutes and 30fps) with the purpose, to preprocess the images for training a neural network.
Loading a stored png-image takes about 10 ms of time with opencv. This is really fast, but you always have to preprocess videos by extracting images from them way before thinking about loading them for training.
So my idea was to only use videos as input in my multiprocessing-keras-dataloader.
I am already able to set the frame index in the cv.VideoCapture() and get the frame. The Problem is the slowness of setting the index. Grabbing a frame takes about 2-3 ms which is way faster than loading a stored image. The problem is that setting the frame-index takes way too long and i don't know how to accelerate that process.

Splitting a long video brings no performance. The required time is always the same.

```py
frame_set_timings = []
frame_read_timings = []
frames = []
batch_size = 10
video = '/mnt/sda/test_video.mp4'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
total_frames = int(cap.get(7))  # total number of frames

for i in range(batch_size):
    random_frame = random.randrange(start=0, stop=total_frames)  # get random frame number
    start_frame_set = time.time()
    cap.set(1, random_frame)  # Set which frame to grab from the video
    start_frame_read = time.time()
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # Read (grab) the image
    end_frame_read = time.time()

    frame_set_timings.append(float("{0:.4f}".format(start_frame_read - start_frame_set)))
    frame_read_timings.append(float("{0:.4f}".format(end_frame_read - start_frame_read)))
    frames.append(frame)

cap.release()

mean_frame_set = float("{0:.4f}".format(sum(frame_set_timings) / len(frame_set_timings)))
mean_frame_read = float("{0:.4f}".format(sum(frame_read_timings) / len(frame_read_timings)))
print('Frame set timings: {list}\nwith a mean time of: {mean}'.format(list=frame_set_timings,
                                                                      mean=mean_frame_set))
print('Frame read timings: {list}\nwith a mean time of: {mean}'.format(list=frame_read_timings,
                                                                       mean=mean_frame_read))
```

The average duration time for seting the index of the required frame is ~56ms. The frame grabbing is about 3ms, what is really fast for my purpose.
I expect the frame-indexing to be faster. Maybe i should use another codec or would it be faster by converting the videos to another format like avi?

Comment: Now i tested using an avi-video, which accelerated the frame-indexing from 56ms to 28 ms. The reading time is now 4ms instead of 2-3ms

Comment: I have never tried this, nor do I have any reason to believe it will necessarily be faster, but you **may** find that it is faster to only seek **forwards** in your video.  So you could generate the batch of frame numbers you want outside the loop and sort them into increasing order and see if that helps... stranger things have happened!

Comment: Seeking in a compressed video generally involves linearly going through each frame from the most recent [keyframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame). It's possible you can use other codecs which store the data raw (i.e.the library can just skip `n_frames*bytes_per_frame` bytes and read off the next image, e.g. ProRes). But as Mark suggests, can you order your random frame indices? This seems doable for your project. Then you can just kinda linearly go through the video with no backtracking, which should speed things up.

Comment: Do you have any update? I face the same problem where using opencv to grab frames from a mp4 video is extremely slow. While if we directly use ffmpeg in command line or grab frames from .mov file, it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found an expensive workaround...

I am converting the mp4-video to a raw-video with FFMPEG with the rawvideo codec and following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -vf scale=768:512 -c:v rawvideo output.3gp
```

But now my video size increased from 18MB to 750MB. That a bit weired and currently i don't know how to decrease the size of the output.

BUT:
The loading time for 6 random frames also decreased from ~500ms to ~20ms. That's awesome and a great result i did not expect.

PROBLEM: I have 271 mp4-videos with a total size of 200GB. If i calculate the faktor of 42 on all videos, my outputs will have a total size of ~8400GB of data.

Any ideas how to reduce this size without purchasing a 12GB HDD?

Comment: Maybe you could re-encode your video with more frequent keyframes which won't cause such a waste of space but may make seeking faster.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes that could be an option. But i am really not familiar with performant codecs and file formats. I will try to use some codecs and formats descriped here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format